# Как использовать алгоритм random_shuffle() на list в c++

Tags: c++, алгоритм

Я пробывал сделать это с помощью итераторов для первой половины списка, но оно выдаёт ошибку

```
    list <int> lis = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10};
    random_shuffle(next(lis.begin()), next(lis.begin(), 5));
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Это не первая половина. Вы игнорируете первый элемент.